# MWS submit feed returns InputDataError

Tags: amazon-mws

I have implemented submit feed API for _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ and get feedsubmission result. it returns InputDataError.

request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>A1OLX7E3BCNOP2</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <MerchantOrderID>114-7129872-3010653</MerchantOrderID>
            <MerchantFulfillmentID>5e79aa3205f4f</MerchantFulfillmentID>
            <FulfillmentDate>2020-03-06T09:00:00Z</FulfillmentDate>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>USPS</CarrierCode>
                <ShippingMethod>First Class</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>9405511298370995607859</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
                <MerchantOrderItemID>60227359610258</MerchantOrderItemID>
                <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>item_5e79aa3205f4f</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                <Transparencycode>AZ:SHGNCW8HKBBB8O4WZKYSHN7GYI</Transparencycode>
            </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>InputDataError</Code>
        <Message>InputDataError</Message>
        <Detail />
    </Error>
    <RequestID>7d4ebf9a-6cb1-4b45-9191-0a00c268982a</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Can anyone help me for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my past experience, MWS is very picky about capitalization (and spelling).   Check TransparencyCode.  You don't have the "c" capitalized.  According to the XSD, it is.   Make sure everything matches.

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderFulfillment.xsd